# Uses-feature android:required="false" being ignored

Tags: android, uses-feature

in my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have these 2 lines:

```
<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

But then when I upload to Google Play, it indicates that the camera is required.  And if i use the aapt tool, it shows: 
"uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'"

Does anyone know why it is ignoring my code and requiring the device to have a camera?

Edit: Here's my entire "uses" section for reference:

```
<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" />

<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-permission                        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission                        android:name="asn.apps.asncrm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission                        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
<uses-permission                        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
```

Comment: Why do you want to ask camera permission without requiring camera hardware?

Comment: There's a spot in the app where they can open up the camera to take a picture.  But that's optional and not required for the rest of the app to run properly.

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but you should use `android.hardware.camera2` since `android.hardware.camera` as been deprecated in API 21. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: what is your minimum sdk?

Comment: minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: The vast majority of your `<uses-feature>` elements are bogus. You cannot just invent new feature names like `android.hardware.INTERNET`. So, start by removing the invalid `<uses-feature>` elements, restricting yourself to [those that actually exist](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference), and see if that helps. I just created a scrap project in Android Studio 1.4.1, added the first four lines from your manifest snippet to the project's manifest, and `aapt dump badging` shows that the features are not required.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this additional tag to your Android manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:required="false"  android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

This reason for this is that, [according to the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission implies the following 2 features are required: `android.hardware.camera` and 
`android.hardware.camera.autofocus`.

[EDITED]

Also, if you have any `<uses-library>` tags in you manifest, one of the libraries may require a camera feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I do already have that in there and edited my answer to provide the rest of my "Uses" section of the androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Do you have any `<uses-library>` tags in you manifest? If so, one of the libraries may require a camera feature.

Comment: I think you're on to something here - i'm referencing the PDF417.mobi's classes.  If they are somehow making the camera be required, is there any way to override that?

Comment: Not that I know of; and I would be surprised if there was a way to override a library's requirements, since that would make the library unreliable and possibly crash your app.

Comment: The library i referenced was a .aar file.  I was able to unzip the .aar file and edit  their AndroidManifest.xml file and add android:required="false" to the camera line. Then re-zip the files and re-build the project and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my application where I want to override the camera permission i.e make the app available for devices without camera, I declare manifest permissions as shown below. I have verified that app is available on play store on devices without camera.

Not sure if this would help you overcome your issue( since you mentioned usage of third party library) but please give it a try and let me know.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" /> // this is the one I have extra, please add and test

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```