# Google Play Console unsupported devices because of android.hardware.camera.autofocus

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I just released an app on Google Play. It shows 1614 devices don't support my app because of this issue:

> Doesn't support required feature 
>   - android.hardware.camera.autofocus

However, my Android Manifest shows this feature as required=false.

Here are the permissions and features I've declared:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Am I missing anything, or have I included anything that would cause the android.hardware.camera.autofocus feature to be required in my app?

For reference this is a React Native app.

Comment: did you used any 3rd party library?

Comment: Yes. Most notably a Video chat library here. https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511847/uses-feature-androidrequired-false-being-ignored